# how can i query data filtered by a JSON Column in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm writing an app using Flask and flask-SQLAlchemy.

I have a `models.py` file as follow

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSON

class Custom(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'custom'

    data = db.Column(JSON)
```

`data` field's value would be like this:

```
[
    {"type": "a string", "value": "value string"},
    {"type": "another", "value": "val"},
    ...
]
```

Now I want to query all `Custom` objects that their `data` field contains an object like this `{"type": "anything", "value": "what I want"}` in the list of objects it has.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON), it can be done using `cast`:

```py
from sqlalchemy.types import Unicode

Custom.query.filter(Custom.data['value'].astext.cast(Unicode) == "what I want")
```

Comment: Documentation for this can be found here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON

Comment: Maybe this answer will be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53196494/6077223

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your table is name "custom" and your json field is named "data" the following sql statement will get your results where the value subfield is equal to "what I want".

```
sql = text("select * from custom where data->>'value'= 'what I want'")
result = db.engine.execute(sql)
```